# If you add extra data space to a DialogBox class be accessed by GetWindowLongPtr, should you add DLGWINDOWEXTRA to access this extra space?

Tags: c, winapi

When creating a window class for use with a DialogBox you need to specify a value of `DLGWINDOWEXTRA` in the `cbWndExtra` member of the `WNDCLASS` struct for "the extra bytes the system requires for each dialog box."  If you add your own additional data space to a DialogBox class which is to be accessed using `GetWindowLongPtr()`, should you add `DLGWINDOWEXTRA` to the offset in order to access your additional space?

(I'll confess that I think I know the answer, and that way the code doesn't break. But, I want to make sure my reasons tally with the collective wisdom.)

The major reason why Dialogs are being used with their own class (rather than the default) is to allow each class of Dialog to have its own Icon.  Two separate items of extra data are also attached to each window.

```
...     
wndclass.cbWndExtra  = DLGWINDOWEXTRA + EXTRASPACE;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) DefDlgProc;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, "ICON_MAIN");
wndclass.lpszClassName = WND_CLASS_VLIST_POPUP;
wndclass.hIconSm = LoadImage(hInstance,
                                 "ICON_MAIN",
                                 IMAGE_ICON,
                                 16,
                                 16,
                                 LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
...
```

Effectively the question is which is correct access to the additional user data I want to add over and above the system required dialog data:

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0 + DLGWINDOWEXTRA + SOMETHING_IN_EXTRASPACE);
```

or

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0 + SOMETHING_IN_EXTRASPACE);
```

?

**NOTE:** Late edit May-15-2009 by David L Morris: *removed the incorrect `GWLP_USERDATA` and replaced with 0*. The original question used `GWLP_USERDATA` in the call to `GetWindowLongPtr()` which is why the accepted answer mentions `GWLP_USERDATA`. The examples above were originally written:

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA + DLGWINDOWEXTRA + SOMETHING_IN_EXTRASPACE);
```

and

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA + SOMETHING_IN_EXTRASPACE);
```

Comment: Apparently, this question is considered subjective by the helper bot?  Bet it is the phrase "tally with the collective wisdom".

Comment: Helper bot isn't that smart. :) 
It's the "you" in the subject... The bot thinks you're referring to me instead of yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually... I think you're making a mistake. The value at `GWLP_USERDATA` and the space allocated according to `cbWndExtra` are two separate things...

The `GWLP_USERDATA` value is part of the space Windows allocates for *every* window. It's so common for window classes to need a pointer-sized bit of storage that Windows just includes it in the base cost of a window, along with all of the other pre-defined "window words". Look at the documentation for the `nIndex` parameter to [`GetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585.aspx):

> Specifies the zero-based offset to the value to be retrieved. Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus the size of an integer.

So, `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0)` retrieves the first `sizeof(LONG_PTR)` bytes allocated in response to `cbWndExtra`,  `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, sizeof(LONG_PTR))` gives you the next pointer-sized data, and so on. As its name implies, `nIndex` acts like an index into an array of bytes (though it always returns a pointer-sized value). Now take a look at the index values assigned to the pre-defined window data constants: they're all negative, including `GWLP_USERDATA`! In effect, `GetWindowLongPtr()` starts indexing into the middle of the window data, with the data common to all windows residing "before" the 0 index, and any window class specific data residing after it.

Dialog windows are built on top of the baseline support provided for normal windows. Since they require more data than normal windows, you're required to specify at least `DLGWINDOWEXTRA` bytes in `cbWndExtra`. Like any other such data, it's accessed via a positive value passed to `GetWindowLongPtr()`.

Therefore, when you ask for

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA + DLGWINDOWEXTRA + 0);
```

...you're actually getting the data at index `-21 + 30 + 0 = 9`: a value somewhere in the dialog manager's own data. Not what you want!

By now you should realize, that when accessing data allocated via `cbWndExtra = DLGWINDOWEXTRA + extra` you only need to offset your request by `DLGWINDOWEXTRA`. So:

```
GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DLGWINDOWEXTRA + 0);
```

...will get you the first element of extra data. `GWLP_USERDATA` should be used *only* when you wish to get or set the one pointer of always-allocated user data associated with every window.

Comment: For some reason I had convinced myself that GWLP_USERDATA was 0 (not -21), though I did know the other values were negative.  I need to re-read this and think it through some more.

Comment: I have fixed the question, and my code (the code that didn't crash) definitely used '0' and not GWLP_USERDATA.  I'm not quite sure where I got that from, probably miss-reading the MSDN documentation while writing the question.

And with the question now corrected the first result is the one that actually worked (consistent with what you are saying).  I thought I had bad code smell.  Glad that I actually had bad question smell.